# Detecting all classes extending trait

Tags: scala, traits

I have the following trait:

```
trait Tr
```

It's being contained in a module `cdl-common`.

I want to detect all classes/objects extending it during compilation of the module `cdl-impl` dependign on `cdl-common`. For instance:

```
class Cls extends Tr
```

In Java, I could use annotation processor and annotate these classes with some annotation and then analyze AST.

Is it possible to do so in `Scala` with macro without annotating the classes?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily using [ClassUtil](http://software.clapper.org/classutil/) .

For usage, you can refer the answer given here: [Get all the classes that implments a trait in Scala using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34530694/get-all-the-classes-that-implments-a-trait-in-scala-using-reflection)